# Excel VBA code to click web button

Tags: html, vba, excel

Need help how to create excel vba code for this

[image]

I'll be needing the codes so I can complete my macro.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well that's not how this site works. Show us what you have tried and we will help modify your code.. It's not just here do my work for me..

Comment: I'am a newbie so I want to learn how to create the code for that cause google search can't provide me a sample just like that code.

Answer (score 2):

> First, you will need to create a reference to:
>
> - Microsoft Internet Controls
> - Microsoft HTML Object Library
>
>   > In VBE, click Tools > References

```
Sub clickLink()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, Url$, doc As HTMLDocument
    Url = "http://UrlToYourLink.com"

    With ie
        .navigate Url
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        doc = .document
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Dim myBtn As Object
    Set myBtn = doc.getElementsByClassName("button rounded")(0)
    myBtn.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The Internet control is used to browse the webpage and the HTML Objects are used to identify the username and password textboxes and submit the text using the control button.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

The program requires references to the following:

```
1 Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft internet controls are a great way to do this, but if you aren't allowed to add new references, here is another way to go about web scraping.
This methode ain't as 'clean' as Microsoft internet controls and HTML object but it gets the job done.

```
Sub GoogleSearch()
Dim ie As Object
Dim objSearchBnt As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim i As Integer

    'initialize counter
    i = 0

    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ie.Visible = True
    
    'navigate to the url
    ie.navigate "Www.google.com"
    
    'Statusbar shows in the buttom corner of excel
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, please wait..."
    
    'Wait until page is ready
    Do While ie.busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    'Store all the elements with input tag
    Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    
    'Go through all input elements
    While i < objCollection.Length
        'input search field
        If objCollection(i).Name = "q" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = "Hello World"
        End If
        'search button
        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" Then
           Set objSearchBnt = objCollection(i)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    
    objSearchBnt.Click
    
    'Clean up
    Set objSearchBnt = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing
    Set ie = Nothing
    
    'Give excel control over the status bar agian
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```